# Как изменить значение ng-model?

Tags: angularjs

Есть такой пример:
**Angular JS:**

```
$scope.changeSelect = function (item){
    if(item == 0){
      // Здесь изменить ng-model элемента
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="city" ng-change="city">
```

Comment: Считается дурным тоном что-либо менять в DOM из кода контроллера. Это прерогатива директив.

Comment: Можно поподробнее узнать зачем вам менять `ngModel` в коде для `select'а` ? Я не вижу смысла кроме того, что нужно выбрать другой пункт `select'а. Иначе стоит завести ещё одну переменную и присваивать ей своё значение.

Comment: Пример какой-то некорректный. Возможно.
Если вам нужно внутри функции changeSelect изменить ng-model элемента select
то тут все просто $scope.city = <new value>;
Если вы что-то другое имели ввиду, то лучше сформулировать правильно вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <select ng-model="city" ng-change="city">
> ```

`ng-change` вычисляет свой аргумент при изменении. В твоём варианте какая-то фигня - прочитали ещё раз поле и всё. Вероятно, должно быть:

```
<select ng-model="city" ng-change="changeSelect(city)">
```

> ```
> // Здесь изменить ng-model элемента
> ```

```
$scope.city = someCity;
```